# How to export scrapped data using FEEDS/FEED EXPORTS in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

**I'm new to webscraping/scrapy and python**

Scrapy version: Scrapy 2.5.1
OS: windows
IDE: pycharm

I am trying to use **FEEDS** option in scrapy to automatically export the scrapped data from a website to download into excel

Tried following solution but didn't work [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953602/how-to-export-data-automatically-to-csv-with-scrapy-feed) not sure what i'm doing wrong here am i missing something?

[image: code from my machine]

i also tried to add the same in my **settings.py** file after commenting custom_settings in my spider class as per example provided in documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=feed#feeds

for now i achieved my requirement using [spider_closed](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-closed) (signal) to write data to CSV by storing all the scraped items data in a array called **result**

```
class SpiderFC(scrapy.Spider):
name = "FC"

start_urls = [
     url,
]
custom_setting = {"FEEDS": {r"C:\Users\rreddy\PycharmProjects\fcdc\webscrp\outputfinal.csv": {"format": "csv", "overwrite": True}}}

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    spider = super(SpiderFC, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    return spider

def __init__(self, name=None):
    super().__init__(name)
    self.count = None

def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    # each item scrapped from parent page has links where the actual data need to be scrapped so i follow each link and scrape data
      yield response.follow(notice_href_follow, callback=self.parse_item,
                                      meta={'item': item, 'index': index, 'next_page': next_page})
       
def parse_item(self, response):
    # logic for items to scrape goes here
    # they are saved to temp list and appended to result array and then temp list is cleared
        result.append(it) # result data is used at the end to write to csv
        item.clear()
        if next_page:
            yield next(self.follow_next(response, next_page))
        
            
def follow_next(self, response, next_page):
    next_page_url = urljoin(url, next_page[0])
    yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

## spider closed signal

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
    with open(output_path, mode="a", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for v in result:
            writer.writerow([v["city"]])
```

when all data is scraped and all requests are completed **spider_closed** signal will write the data to a csv but i'm trying to avoid this logic or code and use inbuilt exporter from scrapy but I'm having trouble in exporting the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your path. If you are on windows then provide the full path in the `custom_settings` e.g. as below

```py
custom_settings = {
    "FEEDS":{r"C:\Users\Name\Path\To\outputfinal.csv" : {"format" : "csv", "overwrite":True}}
}
```

If you are on linux or MAC then provide the path as below:

```py
custom_settings = {
    "FEEDS":{r"/Path/to/folder/fcdc/webscrp/outputfinal.csv" : {"format" : "csv", "overwrite":True}}
}
```

Alternatively provide the relative path as below which will create a folder structure of `fcdc>>webscrp>>outputfinal.csv` in the directory from which the spider is run from.

```py
custom_settings = {
    "FEEDS":{r"./fcdc/webscrp/outputfinal.csv" : {"format" : "csv", "overwrite":True}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My apologies, i'm using windows machine. I did update CUSTOM_SETTINGS with full path but it did not work.

i have made my edits to the question and updated

Comment: The name of the argument is `custom_settings` not `custom_setting`

Comment: modified from **custom_settings** to **custom_setting** and tried with both forward and back slashes but it didn't create the file

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Try save the file just in the same directoty as the script by using ```custom_settings = {
    "FEEDS":{"outputfinal.csv" : {"format" : "csv", "overwrite":True}}
}```

Comment: `custom_setting = {"FEEDS": {r"outputfinal.csv": {"format": "csv", "overwrite": True}}}`

did this but still not able to create the file, i'm kind of sure that i'm missing something here but not sure what it is or i did something wrong.

Comment: the setting to use is `custom_settings` with an s. You are using `custom_setting` which is not correct

Comment: modified it and i was able to see that the file is getting created but its empty.

FYI, i have my data saved in a list named "result"

Comment: simply `yield` your data as dictionaries and they will automatically be saved in the csv file. You don't need the list named `result` e.g. in `parse_item` simply replace `result.append(it)` with `yield it` instead. Assuming `it` is a dictionary like object

Comment: Thank you that was helpful its working now, i think i have to cleanup/formatting for some of the item values that are getting scraped as they have special characters and line breaks but thanks for all the help. I will mark it as answered.

this worked: `custom_settings = {"FEEDS": {r"outputfinal.csv": {"format": "csv", "overwrite": True}}}`

did **yield** on `it`: `yield it` instead of result.append(it)